# C Macro List size resolving but not entering for loop

Tags: c, macros

I have the following code and when I try to use the sizeof list a as a condition in for loop it does not enter it, but if I hard code it, it enters the loop. Why is this behaviour happening?

```c
#include <limits.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MY_VAL (sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]))
#define MY_NEW_VAL 5

int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

int main() {
  int i;
  for (i = -1; i <= (MY_VAL - 2); i++) {
    printf("In loop 1\n");
  }
  for (i = -1; i <= MY_NEW_VAL; i++) {
    printf("In loop 2\n");
  }
}
```

output -->

```
In loop 2
In loop 2
In loop 2
In loop 2
In loop 2
In loop 2
In loop 2
```

My compiler is clang version 15.0.7, running linux as my os. Just in case this is a compiler specific behaviour.

I am aware this is not something to be used in a real world use case, just found this behaviour to be odd. Please explain.

Comment: Can you check the value of `MY_VAL`? What is its value? It seems that you defined it before initializing `a`,  hence the `sizeof` `a` was not yet the value you expected it to be.

Comment: @LajosArpad The macro is substituted before `sizeof` is evaluated.

Comment: @LajosArpad If I print the value of MY_VAL before the for loop it comes out to be 7 and defaults to unsigned long type

Comment: That's a funny one, made me to scratch my head. It is because of the comparison `i <= (MY_VAL - 2)`. The type of RHS is unsigned (because `size_t` is unsigned), so `i` is converted to unsigned as well and is becoming a large value. So the condition is never true. Replace  `i=-1` with `i=0` and it will work.

Comment: @EugeneSh.  Yupp that just might explain the weird behaviour. Since it MY_VAL type is unsigned long the comparisons results in i being converted to unisgned int , which makes i bigger than the list size, whereas MY_NEW_VAL defaults to int type which does change the type of i in the comparison. C is full of surprises.

Comment: For reference: [`sizeof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof) resolves to the type [`size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t), and `(size_t) -1` is [`SIZE_MAX`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sizeof` is of type `size_t`, which is unsigned, whereas your `i` is signed. C is converting `i` to a `size_t`, which makes the -1 a large positive number — greater than `MY_VAL - 2`. So the loop never runs. If you had had sufficient warnings enabled, the compiler would have told you about this possible problem.

`MY_NEW_VAL` on the other hand is of a type derived from the constant value. For this *particular* small value, it is an `int`. So that one works.

Since you want to start at -1, you need to make the limit signed: `for (i = -1; i <= (int)MY_VAL - 2; i++)`. Then it works.

Comment: Godd answer Mark.  I got it but I cannot add anything to what you said.  Good job (my upvote goes to you)